# Programmatically access Google App Engine Quota Details

Tags: java, google-app-engine, quota

Does anyone know if it is possible to access via code either from within App Engine SDK or some form of WebAPI your current account quota details.

I would like to be able to track the datastore usage and bandwidth usage within the running application so that it may alter its behaviour depending on the levels of Quota left for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small [Quota API for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Monitoring_CPU_Usage_in_a_Request) which can count CPU usage. As to the best of my knowledge, there is no Quota API for java.

Comment: This isn't what the OP was asking - they wanted to access remaining quota, not the amount used by the current request.

Answer (score 9):

You can monitor this issue: [api to query quota statistics](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655):

Comment: I have stared this request. Thanks for pointing that one out. Cheers.