# Get remaining queries / quota for API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

How do I programmatically retrieve (ideally through the API) my remaining quota for that same API?  Specifically the Youtube Data API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as of now, there is no tool that can do this or compute the remaining quota used in the API. What can I give you is this [feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/35876330) coming from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767363/programatically-access-google-app-engine-quota-details) that requesting to have a Quota statistics API for the Google Products. But sadly to say, there is no exact date when they will approve and release this API.

What can you do right now is to estimate the remaining quota of your YouTube API by using this [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost). By using this tool, you can now know how much quota that you are using every day.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I starred the request.  Not holding my breath.